# Silverlight 4: Read in file from local system without being OOB?

Tags: silverlight, file, privileges

Any tips/tricks on how to read a file from the local system dynamically in silverlight 4 without having to be out of browser?

Impersonation? Toggling app elevated trust on/off programmatically?
Or is this simply impossible to do without being out of browser?

As it stands I have a Pegasus ImageGear PDF viewer that I feed a "LoadDocument" method a stream of a PDF file.
This of course works fine if the file is an application resource and compiled with the application.

```
StreamResourceInfo resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/TestRIA;component/SampleData/test.pdf", UriKind.Relative));
docViewer.LoadDocument(resource.Stream);
```

This silverlight application will be hosted through a website deployed on a server. This server has a partition specifically for repositories of files. These files in the "D:" partition are currently accessed by an ASPX web application and displayed in a PDF viewer. We're moving to silverlight, so as the user selects the grid row representation of that file in the repository, I know the "NAME" of the file. The repository's location is a string held in the database configured in another application. I simply concatenate the file name to that repository path and have the filepath.

Again, the 3rd party viewer's "LoadDocument" method has two overloads. One that accepts a stream of the PDF and one that accepts the filename of the PDF.

For example I have a click event that feeds the name of the document, and I already have the root path to concatenate it to:

```
void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string docName = myListBox.SelectedItem.Content.ToString();
    docViewer.LoadDocument(repositoryPath + docName);

    //OR using stream

    Stream s = new FileStream(repositoryPath + docName, FileMode.Open);
    docViewer.LoadDocument(s);
}
```

Comment: Do you just need to read these files (not save edits)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot programatically interact with an arbitrary file in SL4. *Period*. There's your section of isolated storage you can read from and write to files, but that isn't what you're looking for. You can read and write files through the file open dialog, but again I think that's not what you want.

The only *way out* of the Silverlight sandbox is the **network**. You have to have to talk to a non-sandboxed service to do this. SL has OK support for Web Services, Http, and even sockets. This seems doable for you since you're talking about the file being somewhere on a "server".

Comment: this sounds promising. so have a simple web service that i call to access the file itself and return it...

do you have a link to a sample of using sockets?

Comment: what if the repository itself was on the server that the silverlight app was hosted on. it would not have an issue accessing those files correct? only files from the actual user's local system?

Comment: Accessing a web service developed in .NET (WCF) is the norm. Here is a pair of links I just googled - [Using web service in SL](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/06/22/consuming-wcf-services-in-silverlight-3.aspx) and [Making a WCF service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWebService.aspx)

Comment: As for your second question about the file living on the same server as the SL host site: SL code runs on the client. It is delivered down to the client by a web server, but that's about it. The only special relationship between the SL app and it's host web site (WRT security) is that you are free to access web services on that machine. Web services on other machines are restricted w/o a cross domain file. **I wonder is ASP.NET isn't a better technology choice for what you want to do**

Comment: I ended up taking the original advice of using network means of actually retrieving the file. I have a WCF service that my RIA consumes and does the file retrieve process for me, returning a byte array of the file itself, then I stream that byte array to the document viewer. Thx to everyone for your comments/advice.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading that this will work without elevated trust only if the code is initiated with a user action such as button click.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382752%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

> For security purposes, if a Silverlight application is a sandboxed
>   application, file and print dialog boxes must be user-initiated. This
>   means you must show them from a user-initiated action, such as the
>   click event handler for a button.

As a possible workaround, if your Silverlight app is backed by a service, you could make the reading/writing of the file be handled by the service, assuming it has access to the location(s) and sufficient rights in the destination folder(s).

Comment: I actually have the path to the file already in the code. This is a silverlight app that will run on a server and the file will reside on another partition of said server. The SL app allows the user to choose the file name (they don't know the full path on the server), and then I tack the full path onto the file name they chose. How can I get the rights to the file that I know is there from that user initiated action?

Comment: is there a way to allow for another event to act as the trigger to that dialog box's confirmation click?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is NO way around the security requirement to have the use interact with the file dialog...

Comment: What about if the file is a UNC path rather than an explicit filepath? like \\12.34.567.891\mydirectory\myfile.pdf rather than D:\mydirectory\myfile.pdf?

Comment: Don't know that would matter. Suppose a highly privileged user is running a Silverlight app. You wouldn't want that app able to read/write by itself to any server's filesystem where he/she has rights. They (MSFT) are trying to protect against that. Hence the word "sandbox".

Answer (score 0):

Create an OpenFileDialog box and you can return stream(s) to the selected file(s).

Comment: I actually have the path to the file already in the code. This is a silverlight app that will run on a server and the file will reside on another partition of said server. The SL app allows the user to choose the file name (they don't know the full path on the server), and then I tack the full path onto the file name they chose. How can I get the rights to the file that I know is there from that user initiated action?

Comment: I couldn't get what you are trying to do, sorry. Please explain (and not here, on the question itself) step by step, with example source code from both the client and the server, and the point you are exactly stuck at, then I can help. I am willing to, but I can't as I don't understand. Hit here when you update it so I'll know.